# Java GUI: Rock, scissor paper game

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, jlist

I am currently learning about GUI development in Java, and I am supposed to make a rock, paper, scissor game. So far I've made the GUI itself (an ugly one, but still a GUI), but I don't know how to "connect" the selection you make into if's and else's. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Oppgave extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public JLabel title;
public JButton button;
public JList liste;
public JList liste2;

public Oppgave(){
    super("A game");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    title = new JLabel("Rock, scissor, paper!");
    add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    String[] choice = {"Rock","scissor","paper"};
    liste = new JList(choice);
    liste.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(liste, BorderLayout.WEST);

    liste2 = new JList(choice);
    liste2.setSelectionMode(DefaultListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    add(liste2, BorderLayout.EAST);

    button = new JButton("Play");
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    button.addActionListener(this);
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(button)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 chose: "+liste.getSelectedValue());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 chose: "+liste2.getSelectedValue());
    }

    }
}
```

So now I want to make if's and else's, like if player 1 picks rock, then check what player 2 picks and display the winner.

How do I use the selections from the JLists in if/else statements?

Comment: Does your output say the correct thing? IE: Player 1 chose: Rock, if he did indeed choose rock? Just create a string and compare the two.

Comment: Yes, the dialog boxes show the correct choices. I just don't know how to continue, could you give an example or something?

Comment: Thanks for both answers. They both worked well, I picked Max's because it was a little easier to work with for a beginner like me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my understanding of what you should attempt to do:

```
String player1Choice = liste.getSelectedValue()
String player2Choice = liste2.getSelectedValue()

if (player1Choice.equals(player2Choice)
    System.out.println("Draw"); // Or whatever you want to output to, could be another jLabel
else if(player1Choice.equals(rock) && player2Choice.equals(paper))
    System.out.println("Player 2 wins.");

// And just keep adding on here.....
```

Comment: You were faster, I give you that. But I typed mine on a phone.

Comment: @azulflame I would have answered earlier, however, I wanted to verify in the comments that he was getting the correct values ;)

Comment: I see that, but it took me 10 minutes to type that on my phone. You posted 8 minutes before. And I worked off of his answer to your comment

Comment: @azulflame: Yeah, well I typed this comment on a phone while driving in the rain on a motorcycle..

Comment: +1 to both the comment and the answer. Haven't had a laugh in a while, and great minds think alike.

Answer (score 2):

So you have the output and don't know what to do?
Example code you may want to use:

```
String p1 = "";
String p2 = "";
if(liste1.getSelectedValue().equals("rock"))
{
    p1 = "rock";
}
if(liste1.getSelectedValue().equals("paper"))
{
    p1 = "paper";
}
if(liste1.getSelectedValue().equals("scissors"))
{
    p1 = "scissors";
}
```

repeat for player 2, using a string called p2. Then:

```
Boolean player2win = false;
Boolean player1win = false;
Boolean tie = false;
if(p1.equals(p2))
{
    tie = true;
}
if(p1.equals("rock") && p2.equals("scissors"))
{
    player1win = true;
}
if(p1.equals("paper") && p2.equals("rock"))
{
    player1win = true;
}
if(p1.equals("scissors") && p2.equals("paper"))
{
    player1win = true;
}
else
{
    player2win = true;
}
```

That should work